# R: replacing df/matrix value by its column name

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

I have a very sparse matrix or data frame (with some 1s and lots of zeros)

```
col1   colAname   colBname   colCname ...
-----------------------------------------
text   0          1          0
text   1          0          0
...
text   0          0          0
```

I wish to replace each "1" value by its column name, like this

```
col1   colAname   colBname   colCname ...
-----------------------------------------
text   0          colBname          0
text   colAname          0          0
...
text   0                 0          0
```

Is there an efficient way to this without using `for` loops ?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```
 df[,-1][!!df[,-1]] <- colnames(df[,-1])[col(df[,-1])][!!df[,-1]]
 df
 # col1 colAname colBname colCname
 #1 text        0 colBname        0
 #2 text colAname        0        0
 #3 text        0        0        0
```

Or

```
  df[,-1][!!df[,-1]] <- colnames(df)[t(t(df[,-1])*(2:ncol(df)))]
```

#### data

```
 df <- data.frame(col1='text', colAname = c(0, 1, 0), 
                           colBname=c(1, 0, 0), colCname=0)
```